# Copy part of text from the same cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem when I downloaded a file containing different kind of information that should be stored in different cells but all is written in the same cell.

For example **A:9** contains:

```
2016.03.16,"8982266507","QLGJG","AHGLG","OKK","IK","ODEADKIK","DK57200028982561607","485979,12","65164,94","485979,12","65164,94","485979,12","65164,94","","","","","","",
```

I would like to have a macro that copies specific parts of this string for example the last part `"65164,94"` and paste in to **cell A:10.**

Thank you in advance

Comment: try the "text to columns" function (In the 'data' tab)

Answer (score 1):

As well as Seb's answer, you can use the split function. So:

```
Sub splitting_string()
Dim arr1 As Variant, var1 As String
var1 = Range("A9")

arr1 = Split(var1, ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
    Cells(10 + i, 1) = arr1(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

This will separate the long string in A9 into smaller ones by splitting them every time there's a comma, placing them in the cells below.